# last visited pages of a site

Tags: custom, user-controls

I have a requirement in which I have to show two previously visited pages in breadcrumb.

Is there any property from which I can fetch this information?

Comment: As far as I know you can't do that. There is no property for such information

Comment: Is there any other way, you are aware of?

Comment: You could store this info yourself in a service application, list or other DB. By shooting in a control via a DelegateControl you could have a control on each and every page. This control can then update the storage

Comment: Yes, I guess that is the last option. Will SharePoint 2013 usage reports help?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable auditing(for view event) to the page library where the pages are stored. After this every access to the page gets stored in the audit logs . You can then fetch the last two visits from the SPAuditEntryCollection .This way you don't have to make an extra effort of making an entry to a list for every access.
You can refer the following link for more information:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spauditentry.aspx

You can get entries by restricting entries to the specified user. Please refer the following link for more details:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spauditquery.restricttouser.aspx

Comment: Hey Thanks for the answer, but it is not applicable in my case. I need this info per user and SPAuditEntryCollection, will hit the performance.